# SFDX not pulling field history tracking for Person Account (__pc fields)

Tags: salesforcedx, person-accounts, history-tracking, field-history

Enabling Person Account creates these fields ending with "__pc" in their API name. That happens when we create a contact field - Salesforce automatically creates the __pc equivalent of the field on the Account object as well. Let's say I crated a "Test__c" on the contact object, so Salesforce automatically creates the "Test__pc" field on the Account object as well. Now, I wanted to enable Field History Tracking for my "test" Person Account field. There are 2 places where I can do this: on the Account or on the Contact. Here are my 2 observations / problems:

1. Enabling Field History Tracking on the Contact object doesn't seem to make any action. If I make a data change to my person account record, and then I query the ContactHistory object via SOQL, nothing comes up (no data). Same observation on the AccountHistory object, no data there as well (no history captured). However, if I enable the Field History Tracking on the Account object, I do see my history recorded in the AccountHistory object. Is this a bug, or by design? If by design, why am I allowed to make changes in 2 places, and one of them doesn't seem to matter anyway?
2. I play it safe and I add my Field History Tracking in both the Account and the Contact. When pulling via SFDX, only the contact Field History Tracking gets pulled and not the Account one. When deploy to another environment, the Field History Tracking on the Person Account doesn't get deployed because as we observed in 1, the contact tracking isn't enough and doesn't seem tp trigger anything. Is this a bug? Why is the Account Field History Tracking not pulled by SFDX? Which is even stranger, SFDX tells me that there is a change, but the source files don't change locally.

To summarize point 2, here how to reproduce the problem:

- In a person Account enabled scratch org, create a contact field Test__c. This will automatically create a Test__pc field on the Account object.
- From the Setup menu and on the Account object, activate field history tracking for Test__pc field
- In the local dev environment, do an sfdx pull. Change is detected but no actual source file changes are pulled from the server.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Person Account is really an Account object with a special record type. As the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.account_person_behavior.htm&type=5) say, the field history is enabled via and based on Account. Should it include Contact fields? That would be expected but this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000U4u5QAC) claims that they aren't included.

Comment: That makes sense. But then why is SFDX pull command not pulling the field history tracking metadata information into my local workspace? I think this might be a bug.

Comment: please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your sfdx issue